# Find friends on Stack Overflow - very common username

Tags: discussion, search

Is there a way on Stack Overflow to search for a friend's profile?

I have a friend and I would like to see his posts sometimes...

Of course I don't remember his user ID all the time but I do know his name in here.

If I type in "Dan" I get about 600 Pages (even more) where people have the same name.

It might help if I could search for the city too, but it seems like this ain't possible.

Comment: Why don't you just bookmark him, or favourite a question he participated in? That way you'll still find him should the user name change.

Comment: this is what i have. but i don't use SOF allways on my pc. im using chrome so i just can login and get my bookmarks. but the actuall question is how can i do this only with SOF :D

Comment: @Dwza: Star one of his questions. Then visit [your favourites](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1906168/dwza?tab=favorites) and access his profile from the question.

Comment: People typically ask their friends to send a link.  Of course, you can't do that when you're only pretend friends with them, and they don't even know who you are.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The search system only lets you specify the name. Although you can search in categories like "moderator" or "new user", or things like "most reputation", this is not helpful in your situation.

One thing you could do is add a link to his profile page in your own profile page.

Another, more complicated way of finding him back is to (ab)use the Favorite system: 
find a question that your friend has asked and mark it as a Favorite (the star under the voting buttons). The question will then show up in your "favorites" tab, and you can see it even if you aren't logged in: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1906168/dwza?tab=favorites

Comment: the favorit thing may helps me with that a lil bit. because i don't use much favs so this could solve it :D

Comment: If you mean by *adding a link to his profile page in your own profile page* to add the friends profile link into about *me* section or website, then this is the real misuse. A favorite is a perfect fit compared to that.

Answer (score 5):

I think it isn't the best way but it is improve your search results:

Go to **Search** then Click on [Users](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=editors) then you can find type of users it will improve your search results[image]

Comment: this not really helps me with my problem because he is: in a list of 600 pages at reputation, not a new user, not a top voter, not a top editor and not a moderator. :)

Comment: he didn't edit a single question ??? Ok tell me name i will give you easy technique.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Google to help with this sort of search. For example, if you search for

```
site:stackoverflow.com "User Dan" Chicago
```

the results give a lot of Dans from Chicago. Of course, you can narrow it down by using more information from your friend's profile.

(This has all sorts of disadvantages - it's not SO native, and thus is likely always slightly out of date, but it is convenient, and fortunately most people's profiles don't change very often...)